# Access to Big Query denied

Tags: google-bigquery, anaconda

I am trying to access Big Query with python in Anaconda. It has been working. However, I used a new project id and I am now getting "Access Denied: Project id: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project id".

Thank you in advance

The same code has been working with a different project id.

```
    import pandas as pd
    sql = "SELECT instance_index, collection_id, machine_id, start_time, end_time FROM `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2019_a.instance_usage` WHERE machine_id = 102894374053"

    project_id = 'vibrant-victory-370720'

    a_102894374053_df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id = project_id, dialect='standard', use_bqstorage_api=True)
```

I don't think it's the problem with the new project since it is working on Google colab, just not on Anaconda.

Should I somehow clean the cache of the authentication of the previous project_id?

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried? Have you set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in your environment?

Comment: Take a look at the instructions here for authenticating when testing locally: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html

Comment: @randomdatascientist, Hi, thank you for your help. I updated my login and project id through my console. However, it's still returning the same error message

Comment: @Rob Thank you Rob, figured out to post the code instead of pics

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by setting the credential with a service account

https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'vibrant-victory-370720-3bafb9420314.json')

a_102894374053_df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id = project_id, dialect='standard', credentials=credentials, use_bqstorage_api=True)
```